# Access slots of objects stored in list in R

Tags: r, list, object, r-s4, slot

The following code produces error:

```
setClass(Class ='Foo', slots=c(field_1='character', field_2 = 'character' ))
list_of_obj <- c(new('Foo', field_1 = 'bar', field_2 = 'foo_bar'))
list_of_obj[1]@field_1


Error: trying to get slot "field_1" from an object of a basic class ("list") with no slots
```

How can I access slot `field_1` in my object stored in list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the double bracket to access the elements of the list, 
single brackets will give you a list object

```
list_of_obj[[1]]@field_1
[1] "bar"
```